# How to calculate sum of Nth power of each cell for a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      A            B        C
396  1147.430  1147.219  0.000184
397  1147.110  1147.630 -0.000453
398  1146.870  1147.469 -0.000522
399  1147.110  1147.680 -0.000497
400  1147.170  1147.640 -0.000410
401  1147.210  1147.430 -0.000192
```

I want to take the Nth power for each cell in Column C and add them up. I know for squares I can use `np.square(df['C']).sum(axis=0)`.
Is there a quick way to do this for other powers?

Comment: Do you know `Python`'s `base**exp` syntax?

Comment: `np.power(2, 3) == 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['C'].pow(3).sum()
Out: -4.2772918200000004e-10
```

Or,

```
(df['C']**3).sum()
Out: -4.2772918200000004e-10
```

Comment: I like this answer better.