# how to substract two successive rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame (python) like this:

```
x   y   z   time
0   0.730110    4.091428    7.833503    1618237788537
1   0.691825    4.024428    7.998608    1618237788537
2   0.658325    3.998107    8.195119    1618237788537
3   0.658325    4.002893    8.408080    1618237788537
4   0.677468    4.017250    8.561220    1618237788537
```

I want to add column to this dataFrame called `computed`. This column includes values computed as for:
row 0: `(0.730110-0)^2  +(4.091428-0)^2 +(7.833503-0)^2`
row 1: `(0.691825 -0.730110)^2 +(4.024428- 4.091428)^2 +(7.998608-7.833503)^2`
etc

How can do that please.

Comment: What language? python? R?

Comment: @U12-Forward PYTHON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

```py
df['computed'] = df.diff().pow(2).sum(axis=1)
df.at[0, 'computed'] = df.loc[0].pow(2).sum()
```

Step by step:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8], 'c': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]})

df
#    a  b   c
# 0  1  1   1
# 1  2  1   4
# 2  3  2   9
# 3  4  3  16
# 4  5  5  25
# 5  6  8  36

df.diff()
#      a    b     c
# 0  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 1  1.0  0.0   3.0
# 2  1.0  1.0   5.0
# 3  1.0  1.0   7.0
# 4  1.0  2.0   9.0
# 5  1.0  3.0  11.0

df.diff().pow(2)
#      a    b      c
# 0  NaN  NaN    NaN
# 1  1.0  0.0    9.0
# 2  1.0  1.0   25.0
# 3  1.0  1.0   49.0
# 4  1.0  4.0   81.0
# 5  1.0  9.0  121.0

df.diff().pow(2).sum(axis=1)
# 0      0.0
# 1     10.0
# 2     27.0
# 3     51.0
# 4     86.0
# 5    131.0

df['computed'] = df.diff().pow(2).sum(axis=1)

df
#    a  b   c  computed
# 0  1  1   1       0.0
# 1  2  1   4      10.0
# 2  3  2   9      27.0
# 3  4  3  16      51.0
# 4  5  5  25      86.0
# 5  6  8  36     131.0

df.at[0, 'computed'] = df.loc[0].pow(2).sum()

df
#    a  b   c  computed
# 0  1  1   1       3.0
# 1  2  1   4      10.0
# 2  3  2   9      27.0
# 3  4  3  16      51.0
# 4  5  5  25      86.0
# 5  6  8  36     131.0
```

Relevant documentation and related questions:

- [Difference between rows with `.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html);
- [Square each cell with `.pow(2)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html);
- [Sum by row with `.sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html);
- [How to calculate sum of Nth power of each cell for a column in dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904340/how-to-calculate-sum-of-nth-power-of-each-cell-for-a-column-in-dataframe);
- [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index).

Comment: The first computed value in row 0 must be 3

Comment: @bib Yes. Because `.diff` doesn't treat the first row the way you want. You can do the first row separately. I edited my answer.

Comment: can we applied the same thing for a subset of columns instead to use all columns let say for only a and b?

Comment: @bib Yes. See this related question: [Pandas: sum DataFrame rows for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns). Just index by the list of column names before performing the operations: `df['computed'] = df[['a', 'b']].diff().pow(2).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @bib And for the first row you can either do it the same way, or write it explicitly: `df.at[0, 'computed'] = df.at[0, 'a']**2 + df.at[0, 'b']**2`